# Implementing Sigmoid Curves in C++

Tags: c++, image, pixel, formula, curve

I've been trying to implement Sigmoid curves since 12 hours ago and i could not manage to get it up.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

The formula is y = 1/(1+exp(-e))

Yet when i try implementing in the codes it does not work, why? Can any experts please guide me along, thank you.

```
for(int y=0; y<bih.biHeight; y++)
{
for(int x=0; x<bih.biWidth; x++)
{   
SetPixel(hdc, (double)1/((double)1+exp(double(-x))), bih.biHeight-x, red);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*?

Comment: Does not work as in it is unable to plot a normal curve as shown in 

http://www.numberlinx.org/Sigmoid%20Curves.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sigmoid Curve not working with formula C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073033/sigmoid-curve-not-working-with-formula-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result for the `(double)1/((double)1+exp(double(-x)))` expression is between 0 and 1. You can't draw "subpixels" can you?

So to fix it, you need to multiply the result of the function by a value that will make it go through a visible range. For example:

```
(double)1/((double)1+exp(double(-x))) * bih.biHeight
```

Comment: SetPixel(hdc, (double)1/((double)1+exp(double(-x)))*bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight-x, red);

Does not work :/

Comment: The lines start from nearly at the bottom right hand of the image, and ends it at the end with a slight curve on the top right hand of the image. Why is that so?